# How to filter LINQ with date

Tags: linq

my code:

```
var query = from s in ctx.location
        join b in ctx.order on s.locationID
        equals b.ID
        join e in ctx.offerdata on b.OrderID
        equals e.OrderID

        where(e.delDate.ToString().Contains("2013"))

       orderby e.identity_no
       select new Order
       {
    ...

       };

      return query.ToList();
```

But this ist not working ... so how must my LINQ look like, that ich can only see Orders of 2013 ...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Well you're really interested in the year, right? So try:

```
where e.delDate.Year == 2013
```

EDIT: As we now know that `delDate` is a `DateTime?` it would be:

```
where e.delDate != null && e.delDate.Value.Year == 2013
```

Comment: @Jocelyn: Well now you're asking a different question - and we can't tell just from that comment what you're trying to check. So ask a new question in a new post, with all the appropriate information (including the types, which you didn't mention in this question).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

e.delDate.Year == 2013

...

Answer (score 2):

If it's a `DateTime` why do you convert it to `string`?

```
var query = from s in ctx.location
        join b in ctx.order on s.locationID
        equals b.ID
        join e in ctx.offerdata on b.OrderID
        equals e.OrderID

        where(e.delDate.Year == 2013)
```